# Campaigns showing up in Google Analytics that I didn't create?

Tags: google-analytics

I created a few UTM campaigns to track in Google Analytics. After a few days, I went to check the campaigns and while the ones I created were there, other campaigns I had not created were also showing up. They had strange, gibberish names. As in, the names are just long strings of characters. The first screenshot shows some campaigns I created ("VBC Campaign (Pilot 1 (5.12.21))" and "VBC Campaign (Pilot 1 (5.12.21))") as well as some I did not ("gebafvgvba_gb_icd_vageb" and "gebafvgvba_gb_icd_xabj_lbhe_cbchybgvba"). The listed source is also gibberish, and the medium is email for each of them (see second screenshot).

How do I figure out how these got created, and how can I get rid of them/prevent them from being created in the future? Thank you!

[Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RmjGD.png)

[Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/on5aV.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try to check if you checked tick to exclude spam and bot in View setting.

Answer (score 0):

There are not many ways (ie: Michele's suggestion) to prevent someone from sending aletory Campaign data to you Google Analytics account. As the UTMs are query paramns we append to a URL, anyone may add these UTMs and click or share the UTMed URL and as it's clicked GA will record these informations.